# ordenar arreglo de forma descendente utilizando recursividad

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento, recursión

Tengo esta parte del programa en donde se introducen 10 números desde el teclado , lo que no se como realizar es la parte del ordenamiento descendente utilizando la recursividad

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursividad {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] miArreglo = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese el número en la posición " + (i) + " :");
        miArreglo[i] = entrada.nextInt();
    }
            System.out.println("El Arreglo sin ordenar es el siguiente:"+ 
Arrays.toString(miArreglo) + " ");

}
}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=quicksort da un par de ejemplos

Comment: ¿Necesitas ordenarlos con algún Algoritmo en especial?, uno de lo más intuitivos aunque no muy eficiente es BubbleSort, existen muchos más algoritmos mucho más optimos, pero si el ejercicio busca aplicar recursividad en un ejercicio sencillo te recomeindo BubbleSort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes crear una función donde hagas la recursividad pasando el array y el tamaño como parámetro:

```
int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90};

bubbleSort(arr, arr.length);
```

Después realizar la recursividad, ten en cuenta que necesitas alguna forma para salir de la recursividad, una condición:

```
 if (n == 1)
     return;
```

Vamos a ordenar el `array` con el método conocido como burbuja:

```
  for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
  {
      if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])
      {

          int temp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[i+1];
          arr[i+1] = temp;
      }
  }
```

Solo tendríamos que volver a llamar a la función de la siguiente forma:

```
bubbleSort(arr, n-1);
```

Te dejo el ejemplo completo:

```
public class MyClass
{
    static void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
    {
        // Base case
        if (n == 1)
            return;

        for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = temp;
            }

        bubbleSort(arr, n-1);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90};

        bubbleSort(arr, arr.length);

        System.out.println("Sorted array : ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto me funcionó muy bien ,gracias por la aportación, lo único que cambie fue que en lugar de que el arreglo se declarará desde el inicio lo introduje por medio de teclado

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro que te funcionará :)

Answer (score 2):

Un método de ordenación muy bueno y además muy rápido es el conocido algoritmo recursivo  de `Quicksort` (algoritmo de ordenación rápida). En [este enlace](https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort) tienes un buen ejemplo con un `array` de `int`. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.